# How can I change mouse behavior depending on the item hovered over with PyQt6 and Pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseevent, pyqtgraph, eventfilter

I'm creating a DICOM image visualization interface with PyQt6 and PyQtGraph. I display the image using an **`ImageContainer`** class, a subclass of **`pg.ImageView`**. I've modified the mouse behavior during click using **`mousePressEvent`** and **`mouseMoveEvent`**. I also display the pixel values hovered by the mouse without clicking, using an **`eventFilter`**.

I allow the user to add an elliptical region of interest (ROI) using a **`CustomEllipseROI`** class, a subclass of **`pg.EllipseROI`**. By default, the ROI is movable and resizable, but since I've modified the mouse behavior of the **`ImageContainer`** instance, it no longer works.

I tried to implement another eventFilter in the **`CustomEllipseROI`** class, but failed.

**Question:** How can I enable the movement and resizing of the ROI again, and even customize the mouse behavior specifically for the ROI?

Here's a minimal reproducible example. Thanks for your help!

````
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent

class CustomEllipseROI(pg.EllipseROI):
    def __init__(self, pos, size, **args):
        super().__init__(pos, size, **args)
   
    def hoverEvent(self, event):
        print("Hover ROI")

class ImageContainer(pg.ImageView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.create_data()
        self.init_image()
        self.create_ROI()

    def create_data(self):
        dataRed = np.ones((100, 200, 200)) * np.linspace(90, 150, 100)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
        dataRed += pg.gaussianFilter(np.random.normal(size=(200, 200)), (5, 5)) * 100
        dataGrn = np.ones((100, 200, 200)) * np.linspace(90, 180, 100)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
        dataGrn += pg.gaussianFilter(np.random.normal(size=(200, 200)), (5, 5)) * 100
        dataBlu = np.ones((100, 200, 200)) * np.linspace(180, 90, 100)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
        dataBlu += pg.gaussianFilter(np.random.normal(size=(200, 200)), (5, 5)) * 100
        self.data = np.concatenate(
            (dataRed[:, :, :, np.newaxis], dataGrn[:, :, :, np.newaxis], dataBlu[:, :, :, np.newaxis]), axis=3
        )

    def init_image(self):
        self.setImage(self.data)
        self.ui.histogram.hide()
        self.ui.roiBtn.hide()
        self.ui.menuBtn.hide()
        self.ui.roiPlot.hide()

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_Hover)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

        self.view.mousePressEvent = self.mouse_press_event
        self.view.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouse_move_event

    def create_ROI(self):
        self.ellipseROI_item = CustomEllipseROI((50, 50), (50, 50))
        self.view.addItem(self.ellipseROI_item)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.HoverMove:
            print("Hover Image")
            # Call function that displays the image value at mouse position
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Type.HoverLeave:
            print("Leave Image")
            # Clear value display
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
    
    def mouse_press_event(self, event):
        self.prevPos = event.pos()

    def mouse_move_event(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.MiddleButton:
            print("Middle Button on Image")
            # Call function to change contrast
        elif event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            print("Left Button on Image")
            # Call function to move across slices of a volume
        elif event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            print("Right Button on Image")
            # Call function to zoom in/out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = ImageContainer()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())```
````

Comment: You don't need to do a monkey patch. Derive a class from the ```pyqtgraph.ViewBox```, override its event handlers, and specify its instance as the ```view``` argument of the ```pyqtgraph.ImageView``` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're overriding the `self.view.mousePressEvent` method without calling the original method. It is best practise to return with a call to the original method of any method you're overriding.

My solution adds the return call to both `self.view.mousePressEvent` and `self.view.mouseMoveEvent` as it is best practise but the bug only occurs because of `self.view.mousePressEvent` specifically.

```
class ImageContainer(pg.ImageView)

    def init_image(self):
        # Other stuff.. .

        self.original_view_mouse_press_event = self.view.mousePressEvent
        self.original_view_mouse_move_event = self.view.mouseMoveEvent
        self.view.mousePressEvent = self.mouse_press_event
        self.view.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouse_move_event
    
    
    def mouse_press_event(self, event):
        self.prevPos = event.pos()
        return self.original_view_mouse_press_event(event)
    
    def mouse_move_event(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.MiddleButton:
            print("Middle Button on Image")
            # Call function to change contrast
        elif event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            print("Left Button on Image")
            # Call function to move across slices of a volume
        elif event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            print("Right Button on Image")
            # Call function to zoom in/out
        return self.original_view_mouse_move_event(event)
```

Comment: Actually, "it is best practise" to *subclass* and properly override the related functions, eventually calling the base implementation (possibly returning the expected type). Monkey patching should be only done if one is completely aware of its implications, and should generally be avoided for event handlers.

Comment: @Sen Zmaki, thanks for your help. With this code, everything before "return" seems to be ignored. For example, "Middle Button on Image", "Left Button on Image", etc. are no longer displayed. I'll try to subclass "pyqtgraph.ViewBox" as suggested by relent95 and musicamante, although I'm not sure how to properly modify the event handlers in this class.